# Changing columns for Excel userform comboboxes

Tags: excel, vba, userform, combobox

Good morning,

I am in yet another rut and need some help.  I have created a user form that allows a user to delete an entire rows worth of data on a second sheet (rawdata).  Everything works fine using the code below, however the combo box ONLY shows the row number.  I am in desperate need of changing the column so it will show the project names of the rows that need to be deleted.

Example:

```
Row:  Project
1     Alpha
2     Beta
```

I would like the combo box to show Alfa and Beta and have the user be able to select the row they would like to delete based on that criteria.

The code below unhides and then hides the sheet that I want this deletion to occur on.  This was done with purpose.

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim lRw As Long
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RAWDATA").Visible = xlSheetVisible
     'get the row number. add 1 because ListIndex starts at zero
    lRw = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RAWDATA").Select
    Cells(lRw, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RAWDATA").Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
     'assumes data starts in A1 and has a header row
    Me.ComboBox1.List = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RAWDATA").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Value
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have a column called 'row'?

Comment: You just need to change the number of columns in the `ComboBox` properties and then change the linked range to 2 columns as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.Cells(1, 1)` to `.Cells(1, 2)`

The Cells() method gives the code co-ordinates to a specific range using the row and the column number like so:

```
Cells(r, c)
```

so in your original code, the .Cells(1, 1) points to "A1" and then uses .CurrentRegion to get all cells within the region of A1.

By replacing the column number and using .Cells(1, 2) we tell it to look at "B1" instead - therefore shifting the column over to the right.

EDIT:

You could apply this logic to the Offset(r, c) function to shift the returned value over by 1 column - so:

```
.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 1)
```

This will more than likely be the culprit as the .Cells() method will point to a specific cell, but the .CurrentRegion() method will return the same result regardless unless we offset it.

Comment: Please explain your solution so the OP understands what and why this solution would work.

Comment: For some reason this is still pulling the first column of the sheet.  Also, when I don't want to delete a row and hit the "X" to close the form - the script still runs and deletes the row!!!  BTW - I greatly appreciate the help.  This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Well there ya go!
Crazy offsets, driving me nuts.
After tinkering around and using your suggestions we got it done!  Now I just need to figure out how to not have it error out every time I select something in the drop box, but exit out!  Its weird because it wants to run the script on exit.  Thanks again.